# Has anyone tried Mediatemple (ve) for Rails Apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Mediatemple Rails Grid Container is going to close... so I have to migrate my App. Has anyone tried Rails on Mediatemple (ve) ? or do you recomend something else like Linode or Slidehost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got three Linux (ve) servers with MT and they've been running continuously for over 200 days with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS + Passenger serving Rails 2.x and Rails 3 sites.  You could perhaps ask them for this option?

Just a few days back I purchased a Linode account for my personal dev stuff and got a similar setup running fine without any issues.  A colleague of mine swears by liquid web and there's also Slice Host and Rack Space to consider.  Good luck!

Cheers, M.

Comment: I've been chatting with mt's sales team. According to their rep, they only have Ruby 1.8.5. Do you know if this is true or if their is a way to get a new version of Ruby running? Ideally, I'd like to run Rails 3.1

Comment: If you get a (ve) server you can install RVM and install ANY version of Ruby you like!  I'm running 1.9.2 as we speak =)